# Is it possible to download list of In-App purchases from the iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have around 400 In-App purchase item in one of our apps and we would like to download a list of the products identifiers of those items but I'm not able to figure it out. Is there any official way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/ShowUI.html) says it's not possible

It says:

> Your app can either read its list of product identifiers from a file
>   in its app bundle or fetch them from your server.

and

> There’s no runtime mechanism to fetch a list of all products
>   configured in iTunes Connect for a particular app.

Answer (score 1):

Last year when you were asking this question, I stumbled on the way to do it. I want to generate the report again and went looking for how I did it and saw your question.

You can do this by going to iTunesConnect and select Catalog Reports from the ... menu.[image]

The report will be generated and you'll get an email when it's done.